# How can i change :hover styles on material-ui outlined select?

Tags: css, reactjs, select, material-ui, styles

I am working on a react application using Material UI. I'm trying to make my selector change color to white when I hover over it. But it seems that the way I am doing it does not apply, and when applying other classes directly it does not do it when I want it to.

I almost solvet it using:

```
':hover &.MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
      borderColor: WhiteAlien,
    },
```

But it seems that it applied the styles in other components, that's why the function was launched in moments when it should not

This is the code that im using:

````
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const WhiteAlien = "#fcfcfc";
const SpaceRed = "#d90429";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(4),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  select: {
    color: WhiteAlien,
    borderColor: WhiteAlien,
    "&.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: WhiteAlien,
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "gray",
      "& :hover": {
        borderColor: WhiteAlien,
      },
    },
  },

  inputLabel: {
    color: WhiteAlien,
    "&.MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-focused": {
      color: WhiteAlien,
    },
  },
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const classes = useStyles();

  const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    changeLanguage(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.inputLabel}
          id="lenguage-selector-input-label"
        >
          {t("Navbar.select_title")}
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          className={classes.select}
          labelId="lenguage-selector-label"
          id="lenguage-selector"
          value={i18n.language}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label={t("Navbar.select_title")}
        >
          <MenuItem value={"es_ES"}>Castellano</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={"en_EN"}>English</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind,
finally, i solved the problem editing the theme with some function provided from material.
Finally the code showed up like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const WhiteAlien = '#fcfcfc';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(4),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  select: {
    color: WhiteAlien,
  },
  inputLabel: {
    color: WhiteAlien,
    '&.MuiFormLabel-root.Mui-focused': {
      color: WhiteAlien,
    },
  },
}));

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        '& $notchedOutline': {
          borderColor: 'gray',
        },
        '&:hover $notchedOutline': {
          borderColor: WhiteAlien,
        },
        '&$focused $notchedOutline': {
          borderColor: WhiteAlien,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const classes = useStyles();

  const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    changeLanguage(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel className={classes.inputLabel} id="lenguage-selector-input-label">
            {t('Navbar.select_title')}
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            className={classes.select}
            labelId="lenguage-selector-label"
            id="lenguage-selector"
            value={i18n.language}
            onChange={handleChange}
            label={t('Navbar.select_title')}
          >
            <MenuItem value={'es_ES'}>Castellano</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'en_EN'}>English</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```